# How can I find the memory usage on my GPU?

Tags: nvidia, gpu, memory-usage

Previously I was checking the memory usage on my GPU with the following command:

```
nvidia-settings -q all | grep Memory
```

I am processing some scientific data on my GPU with `numpy` and `theano`. I was doing this with the gnome desktop running, and there was already 380 Mb of memory used on the device. So I stopped lightdm to free up a little more GPU memory; but, now the nvidia-settings tool no longer works.

It simply errors that there is no display

```
ERROR: Cannot open display ':0.0'.
```

Is there some other way of getting GPU memory without using this tool? Is there some way to use make it function in headless mode?

Comment: Mitch (credit to) gives the answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/387594/how-to-measure-gpu-usage nvidia-smi

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/387594/how-to-measure-gpu-usage?

Answer (score 37):

For Nvidia GPUs:

```
nvidia-smi
```

For Intel GPUs:

```
intel_gpu_tools
```

For AMD GPUs:

```
aticonfig --odgc --odgt
```

For real time watching -- example:

```
watch nvidia-smi
```

Comment: +1. Just a headsup: `intel_gpu_tools` (underscore, not dash), as a command.

Comment: `watch nvidia-smi` will do it, no need for `sudo` there I think.

Answer (score 4):

I think the better way is to install a utility [nvtop](https://github.com/Syllo/nvtop)

E.g. In the following picture almost 100% memory is used on all 3 GPUs as per nvtop.
command is

```
nvtop
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check memory usage for every 1 second, then the watch command does the job.

```
watch -n 1 nvidia-smi
```